# Multiple pricebooks using quotes?

Tags: apex, pricebook

Is it possible to have multiple quotes related to the same opportunity that use different pricebooks?

For example, if you have one pricebook setup for 12-month pricing (subscriptions) and another for 24-month pricing, is it possible to create 2 quotes on the same opp -- one presenting 12 month pricing and another for 24 month pricing and then sync whichever term the customer selects?